# gradient descent update rule in sklearn's tSNE implementation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gradient-descent, tsne

In sklearn's tSNE implementation, the gradient update is done as follows (gradient_descent function in _t_sne.py on sklearn's github):

```
    error, grad = objective(p, *args, **kwargs)
    grad_norm = linalg.norm(grad)

    inc = update * grad < 0.0
    dec = np.invert(inc)
    gains[inc] += 0.2
    gains[dec] *= 0.8
    np.clip(gains, min_gain, np.inf, out=gains)
    grad *= gains
    update = momentum * update - learning_rate * grad
    p += update
```

What is unclear to me is where the += 0.2 and *= 0.8 come from. I couldn't find anything in the original t-SNE paper and I can't reconcile the updates in the sklearn implementation with the update formula in the paper:
[tSNE paper gradient update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0c9L.png)

Does anybody know the logic behind the implementation or how I can reconcile the two?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The original tSNE paper mentioned origin of the this update rule: it is basically a way to dynamically increase (+=0.2) or decrease(*=0.8) the learning rate. It is simple and worked well in most cases.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your answer! Could you point me to where in the paper this is mentioned?  They mention some optimisation tricks in section 3.4 and reference Jacobs 1988 - is that it?

Comment: Yes, that's it. The adaptive learning rate basically make the choice of initial learning irrelevant.